# How does the Search synonyms module work?

Tags: 7

I've just activated the [search synonyms module](http://drupal.org/project/searchsynonyms) for D7, but I don't get how it works at all. Where do I set synonyms, I've tried editing forms or check the settings, but I can't find any new input where synonyms could be added. Also I could not find any documentation for the module. Probably me overlooking things but some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jasper, I had a look at the code in the module. There is only one function in the module, and I don't think the module does what is says in the description on the Drupal project page.

Comment: To elaborate, the module relies on the `taxonomy_get_synonyms()` function, which was removed in Drupal 7. So yeah, the Drupal 7 version will do nothing except throw an exception. Why it's marked as having a stable release I can't imagine. @Jasper You might be able to use [Synonyms](http://drupal.org/project/synonyms) instead, there seems to be some overlap

Comment: Do'h, well that's disappointing. I'll take a look at the other module, thanks for your help both!.